# Return value from function and use in react jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JSX code in which i need to call a Javascript pure function which returns a value and use that value in the same as shown below

```
<ListItemText title={"Details"} primary={<span className={compStyle && classes[compStyle]}></span>} secondary={content} />
```

Pure JS func:

```
const getDetails = (arrDetails, time1, time2) =>{
    //execute business logic and return string
    return "Details here"
 }
```

How can i call `getDetails` function in `ListItemText` JSX and get the returned value and use it in `title={"Details"}` and other places like `span` within the same JSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't re-use function computations directly in JSX. However, you can store the result in a variable and then pass it to different component props in JSX.

```
const ListItemTextWithDetails = () => {
   const details = getDetails()

   // here we are passing `details` to two properties 
   // in this way reusing the computed value
   return <ListItemText title={details} primary={<span>{details}</span>} />
}

// somewhere else - render that component
<ListItemTextWithDetails />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an IIFE

```
(() => {
 const val = getDetails();
 return <ListItemText title={val} primary={<span className={compStyle && classes[compStyle]}></span>} secondary={val} />
})()
```